# Want to take nested JSON data(count value) through java

Tags: java, json, rest, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

```
{
 "success": true,
 "data": {
 "count": 0,
 "list": []
 }
}
```

I have a json data where I want to check count and print it's value

First of all I am using jsonpath() function because it's rest-assured and putting response inside it

```
ArrayList a = response.jsonPath().get("data");
```

Above code is giving an error :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Comment: You should try `int count = response.jsonPath().getInt("data.count");`

Comment: Please read the error message carefully. You cannot assign a HashMap to an ArrayList.

Comment: Using JSONObject it is working as well with data.count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use `JsonPath` like this:

```
int count = response.jsonPath().getInt("data.count");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` property contains a json object not a json-array. Therefore, you cannot cast it to an ArrayList. It should be,

```
Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>)response.jsonPath().get("data");
int count = ((Number) data.get("count")).intValue();
```